# parse integers and print out characters

Tags: c

What I'm basically suppose to do is read a line of input e.g.

```
67 5 43 23
```

add two integers at a time, matching them with their corresponding ASCII code. So the first two integers (67 + 5) would correspond to the letter H. I've been able to read the lines, store them in a char array but they're all separate i.e. the first three contents in the array would be 6, 7, and a blank space. So I used `strtok` to detect the blank spaces and was even able to print out

```
67 5 43 23
```

separately but  now I'm confused, do I need to make a new array  to do the task (if so, how can transfer the contents over) or am I over complicating myself.

Comment: why don't you read these numbers as `int`? And please add your source code here.

Comment: If only there were a way in C to **scan f**ormatted information rather than single characters as you do with `fgetc()`? I think, if I were to invent such a thing, I'd probably call it something like `scanf()` :-)

Comment: Well, maybe, but that would be too obvious. I think it would probably be called something like `strtol` and it would include an `endptr` allowing you to convert the next number as well. Or maybe something even more cryptic like `atoi`?

Answer (score 1):

Read with `scanf` the numbers as `ints` and then when displaying, just cast them to a `char`. [Here](http://ideone.com/rMcQbW) is an example. (You will need to modify it to suit your case)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution with hard-coded values. But it puts the point across

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int n, i;
 int new_arr[10], arr[10];
 n = 4;
 printf("Enter elements\n");
 for (i=0;i<n;i++){ 
  scanf("%d",&arr[i]);   //Or store and retrieve in file as integers
 }
 for (i=0;i<n-1;i++){    
  new_arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
 }
 for (i=0;i<n-1;i++){ 
  printf("%c",new_arr[i]);
 }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the file reading part?

Answer (score 0):

Like just about everything in C, there are usually several ways to approach it. Separating a stream of digits into individual numbers is no different. You have two primary approaches, (1) use a formatted read that will read a number at a time from a stream, like `scanf`, or (2) parse the individual characters into their string representations yourself and call a conversion routine such as `atoi()` or `strtol`.

With `scanf`, you will simply read numbers from `stdin` until the input buffer is empty:

```
while (scanf ("%d", &yourvar) == 1) {
   /* ... do something with yourvar ... */
}
```

In the second case, you will either read one-char at a time until you find a digit, then you will save/read/save the digits in a string until you encounter a `space`, then convert the string to an numeric type (e.g. `int`) with `strtol` or `atoi`, handle that number, and repeat until you read a `'\n'` or `EOF`.

The alternative is to read the entire line at once with `fgets` or `getline` into a buffer, then you will basically parse the buffer in much the same way you would separate the numbers reading a character at a time.

There should be many examples already on SO. Here is a simple example showing one way to handle collecting 2 numbers for your sum:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int idx, n, n1;
    idx = n = n1 = 0;   /* always initialize your variables  */

    while (scanf ("%d", &n) == 1) 
    {
        if (idx == 0) { /* check simple 0/1 toggle for n, n1 */
            n1 = n;
            idx = 1;
        }
        else {          /* second number, find sum and char  */
            int sum = n1 + n;
            if (' ' <= sum && sum <= '~')
                printf (" sum = (%2d + %2d) = %3d  =>  %c\n", 
                        n1, n, sum, sum);
            else
                printf (" sum = (%2d + %2d) = %3d  => (out of ASCII range)\n", 
                        n1, n, sum);
            idx = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/scanf2digitsum scanf_2digitsum.c
```

**Example Use**

```
$ echo "67 5 43 23" | ./bin/scanf2digitsum
 sum = (67 +  5) =  72  =>  H
 sum = (43 + 23) =  66  =>  B
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to read as int

```
int a, b;
while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2) {    // Read two integers every time
    printf("%c ", a + b);      // Print char corresponding to ASCII value
}
```

This may run infinitely, it is for illustrative purpose only. You can provide a better loop termination condition.